# Using References in JSONS?

Tags: javascript, json, reference

Say I have a javascript object or a JSON which contains some data:

Person:

```
{
name:
children: [
            Child1, 
            Child2
          ]
}
```

Now I want the Children to also be `Person` objects. However, a child of person A can also be a child of Person B (and of infinite many people let's say).

How can I create a relational structure like this with my JSON file format? Or is this simply unsuitable and I would be better off with something like SQL?

Asked differently: Is there any way to reference objects in my JSON? (I obviously dont want to save the same child twice in two different people and then have to edit both whenever something changes)

Comment: Why not give each object a unique ID, and use those IDs in your lists of children?

Comment: "Say I have a javascript object or a JSON which contains some data" First, what is it? What do you have? An object or a string? strings cannot contain references. But `JSON.parse()` and `JSON.stringify()` can take as a second argument a function wich you could use to "clean up" the data when serializing and parsing. In this case, maybe replace the duplicates with something like `"$person-id:12345"`, and on the parsing step looking for Strings like that and converting them back to reference the proper object.